# Firebase Deploy Cloud Functions - 60 errors all at once

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I haven't made any updates to my Firebase Cloud Functions for a while. I was just making a simple change to a String, so I know it can't be a code issue in the index.ts file. When I tried to deploy, Firebase asked me to update node and other components, which I did and then I tried to run the deploy command.

I was hit with 60 errors that look like this (I'm just including the first few since they all follow a similar format):

```
node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/generated/grpc/channelz/v1/ChannelTrace.d.ts:2:13 - error TS1005: '=' expected.

2 import type { Timestamp as _google_protobuf_Timestamp, Timestamp__Output as _google_protobuf_Timestamp__Output } from '../../../google/protobuf/Timestamp';
              ~

node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/generated/grpc/channelz/v1/ChannelTrace.d.ts:2:119 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

2 import type { Timestamp as _google_protobuf_Timestamp, Timestamp__Output as _google_protobuf_Timestamp__Output } from '../../../google/protobuf/Timestamp';
                                                                                                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/generated/grpc/channelz/v1/ChannelTrace.d.ts:3:13 - error TS1005: '=' expected.

3 import type { ChannelTraceEvent as _grpc_channelz_v1_ChannelTraceEvent, ChannelTraceEvent__Output as _grpc_channelz_v1_ChannelTraceEvent__Output } from '../../../grpc/channelz/v1/ChannelTraceEvent';
              ~

node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/generated/grpc/channelz/v1/ChannelTrace.d.ts:3:153 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

3 import type { ChannelTraceEvent as _grpc_channelz_v1_ChannelTraceEvent, ChannelTraceEvent__Output as _grpc_channelz_v1_ChannelTraceEvent__Output } from '../../../grpc/channelz/v1/ChannelTraceEvent';
                                                                                                                                                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/generated/grpc/channelz/v1/ChannelTrace.d.ts:4:13 - error TS1005: '=' expected.

4 import type { Long } from '@grpc/proto-loader';
              ~

node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/generated/grpc/channelz/v1/ChannelTrace.d.ts:4:27 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

4 import type { Long } from '@grpc/proto-loader';
                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/generated/grpc/channelz/v1/Channelz.d.ts:1:13 - error TS1005: '=' expected.

1 import type * as grpc from '../../../../index';
              ~

Found 60 errors.
Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code2
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: The update to node and packages broke your code. That's the reason. You just have to go and fix all the problems manually.

Comment: From this similar [issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/404) I would recommend updating your typescript library to the latest version. Also, based in this [issue](https://github.com/DashboardHub/PipelineDashboard/pull/1253) you should update
_the `new Date()` to `firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date())` in services_

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue today and resolved it by updating the following.

```
cd functions
```

```
npm install --save firebase-functions@latest
```

```
npm install --save firebase-admin@latest
```

```
npm install typescript --save
```

```
firebase deploy --only functions:YOUR_FUNCTION_NAME
```

You may only need typescript, but this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

When I was trying to run firebase serve I had the same issue, 60 errors in the functions and common folder, due to missing dependencies (of dependencies, which do not get installed somehow).

I ran `yarn` and it gave me warnings, which also explained what's missing and where.

```
% yarn
yarn install v1.22.17
[1/5]   Resolving packages...
[2/5]   Fetching packages...
[3/5]   Linking dependencies...
warning "workspace-aggregator-... > PATH/common > react-mapbox-gl@4.6.0" has unmet 
peer dependency "prop-types@^15.6.2".
```

This was one of the warnings. After `yarn add prop-types` in the common folder, this disappeared. I updated each warning manually, which fixed the issues for me. One of the things I had to update was typescript, that solved 48/60 errors, but then I had to solve the rest almost one by one.